# TreeViewItem is getting grayed automatically on right clicking on it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

On selecting through left click it appears like this.

[image]

On Selecting through right click it appears like this

Here you can see although context menu is opened but the Item book got grayed out.
[image]

How can we resolve this problem.

I have created Tree and its Context menu through Code not through XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is goverend by some resources, the unfocused item will have the brush that can be foundusing the `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey`, so you can override the brush that will be found by using the same key locally:

```xml
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                             Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

The forground will normally still change but you seem to have overridden that already.

*(You should use more XAML by the way)*